# Querying a Database, SQlite, Unable to open Database

Tags: sqlite

I am having some trouble opening a database. I downloaded the db file, though Sqlite will not show the tables for the database, I did the following:

Unziped the db file

Entered this: sqlite3 DATABASE_NAME

Entered: .tables

I get this error:

Error: unable to open database "musicbrainz-cmudb2020.db": unable to open database file

Do I need to do anything special to sqlite in order to use the database?

Comment: Are you running `sqlite3` from the same directory the database file is in? If not, do so or use a proper path to it.

Comment: And if you are (Using a non-existent filename usually creates a new empty datase), are you sure it's a sqlite3 database and not some other type of file?